# Characterization of symmetric group elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $S_n$, $A_n$ denote the symmetric group and alternating group, each on $n \in \mathbb{N}$ letters respectively. Is there a way to characterize all elements $\alpha \in S_n$ satisfying the equation $\{g\alpha g^{-1}|\;g\in S_n\}=\{g\alpha g^{-1}|\;g\in A_n\}\:$?

I was wondering for what elements of the symmetric group on $n$ letters one can arrive at all conjugate (in $S_n$) by conjugating only by even permutations. I know of a sufficient condition on $\alpha \in S_n$ for the above equation to be satisfied - $\alpha$ commutes with at least one odd permutation. I tried computing explicitly for a few elements in $S_3$ and $S_4$ without much fruition. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Shaun As a new SE user, I was unaware of its working. Thank you for taking the time to give detailed guidelines. I've edited my question as instructed. Hope it's fine now :)

Comment: You're welcome. Thank you for improving your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sufficient condition, that $a$ commutes with at least one odd permutation, is also necessary, provided $n\geq2$ so that there is an odd permutation.

To prove it, let $h$ be an odd permutation. Then, by assumption, $hah^{-1}=gag^{-1}$ for some even permutation $g$. Multiplying on the left by $h^{-1}$ and on the right by $g$, you get $ah^{-1}g=h^{-1}ga$. Thus, $a$ commutes with the odd permutation $h^{-1}g$.